# Is there an async way of downloading an image with ImageIcon and URL?

Tags: java

When I fetch an image from an URL, I can't find a way to show a loading icon while it gets downloaded. Here's my method:

```
    private void fetchAdImage(String clickedLink) {
        try {
            // This gets completely ignored \/
            adDisplayLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MainFrame.class.getResource("/icons/spinner.png")));
            // /\
            URL link = new URL(clickedLink);
            ImageIcon adImage = new ImageIcon(link, "");
            int difference;
            if (adImage.getIconHeight() > adDisplayLabel.getHeight()) {
                difference = adImage.getIconHeight() + adDisplayLabel.getHeight();
            } else {
                difference = adImage.getIconHeight() - adDisplayLabel.getHeight();
            }
            adDisplayLabel.setIcon(drawBorder(Tools.getResizedIcon(adImage, adImage.getIconWidth() - difference, adDisplayLabel.getHeight())));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The idea is to change the JLabel's Icon to a "spinner" image on the "onPreUpdate" phase, and to change to the downloaded image on the "onSuccess" phase. The problem is: There's no such thing with this method of downloading, the prior statement gets completely ignored. Is there an async way of downloading an image in Java?

Comment: Wrap the fetching code in a [`SwingWorker`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html)?

Comment: Thank you very much @Slaw, I did not know this class :o I've managed to do it, I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem thanks to @Slaw's suggestion (Wraping the code in a [SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html), a class that I did not know). Here's the code:

```
    private void fetchAdImage(String clickedLink) {
        try {
            SwingWorker<ImageIcon, Void> worker = new SwingWorker<ImageIcon, Void>() {
                ImageIcon adImage;
                int difference;

                @Override
                protected ImageIcon doInBackground() throws Exception {
                    adDisplayLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon(MainFrame.class.getResource("/icons/spinner.png")));
                    URL link = new URL(clickedLink);
                    adImage = new ImageIcon(link, "");

                    if (adImage.getIconHeight() > adDisplayLabel.getHeight()) {
                        difference = adImage.getIconHeight() + adDisplayLabel.getHeight();
                    } else {
                        difference = adImage.getIconHeight() - adDisplayLabel.getHeight();
                    }
                    return adImage;
                }

                protected void done() {
                    adDisplayLabel.setIcon(drawBorder(Tools.getResizedIcon(adImage, adImage.getIconWidth() - difference, adDisplayLabel.getHeight())));
                }
            };
            worker.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```